# Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] Teradata: [Teradata Database] [3119] Continue request submitted but no response to return

Tags: powerbi, teradata

```
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] Teradata: [Teradata Database] [3119] Continue request submitted but no response to return..
'.
```

When trying to connect a View to my power bi file, I get the above error when around 25M records are imported. I do not have any issue on smaller tables.

[image: Error Pic]

Comment: This error generally means some other error was previously raised but the application ignored it and tried to continue fetching data. Check with your DBA to see if the query is being terminated on the database end for some reason, e.g. exceeding some workload management threshold, or perhaps what the first error was.